# Which selector is faster?

Tags: jquery

I'm searching for the existance of one matching selector.  Which is faster?

```
$('a[rel="something"]').first().length > 0)
```

or

```
$('a[rel="something"]').length > 0)
```

Thanks!

Comment: No idea which is faster, but the first is definitely more redundant. If you just want to see whether *anything* is selected, there's not much of a point cherry-picking the `first()` match.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$('a[rel="something"]').length > 0)` should be faster because it does not have overhead of picking up (finding out) the `first()` element in the wrapped set `$('a[rel="something"]')`.

And if you are targeting one element with `$('a[rel="something"]')`, using `first()` isn't needed anyway.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking. Thanks!  In theory would .first() make it stop traversing the DOM on the first match?

Comment: @Joel Crawford-Smith: Welcome.

Comment: To be literally, in both cases selector is the same fast, because it's identical: `a[rel="something"]`. I think you're asking time needed to execute that lines of code. So second will be faster, because `first` is filtering method, which must be called in first case - and it will take some (little little little) time.

Comment: @singles: Yeah true performance difference is absolutely negligible there unless even small bit is considered :)

Answer (score 1):

`$('a[rel="something"]').length > 0)` is faster.